# Java build path error- spring framework

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I imported a sample project into my workspace and when i tried executing it, I found build path errors as

```
.../springframework/..3.1.0 release.jar(missing)
.
.
.
.
.//all such framework .jar files missing
```

I tried importing spring framework libraries all those missing libraries shown in the build path, but couldn't solve the errors.(i have imported spring release of 4.0.5 version)

If i need to only import 3.1.0 release, please do share the link from where i have to download the required libraries.

Comment: Do you use maven for your project?

Comment: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/3.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: yeah.. am using maven

Comment: Try **Maven Reimport**

Comment: I even tried that.. but unable to fix the errors :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add spring jar dependency into `pom.xml` then click on mvn clean & install.

Comment: can i have a step by step procedure to add those jar files? please

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>       i tried adding all these codes in the xml file..

Answer (score 1):

Probably the project you imported has absolute references to the Spring jars. Right click on the project and go to Properties/Java Build path/Libraries. Remove the absolute references and add the new ones.

Concerning the Spring 3.1 jars, you can download them from here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core/3.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: i added new ones and removed the missing .jar files, now i am facing errors with the source java files

Comment: Probable, you didn't add all tthe ones you removed.